# calculate the quarter from a string value in hive

Tags: string, date, hive, type-conversion, hiveql

I have a requirement to fetch the quarter from a string field using hive version less than <1.3 so cant use quarter feature

sample data format in string field say abc--20210415

I tried doing it by using

`CONCAT('T',(INT((MONTH(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(abc,'yyyymmdd')))-1)/3)+1))`

but its showing T1 instead it should show T2 (since april comes in second quarter 20210415) but this expression does not convert string to date before calculating quarter

So, i converted it to date using casting
`cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date, 'yyyymmdd'))) as date)`

it converted but  output was 2021-01-15 and the same was converted to quarter using
`CONCAT('T',(INT((MONTH(cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(qc_creation_date, 'yyyymmdd'))) as date))-1)/3)+1))`

Is there a way around to resolve this issue where in for ex: string 20210415 should give the output as T2 .Kindly help

Regards

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution

`CONCAT('Q',(INT((MONTH(cast(to_date(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(abc, 'yyyyMMdd'))) as date))-1)/3)+1))`

Thanks

Comment: the same can be done much simpler, see the answer

Comment: ceil(regexp_extract(abc,'^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})',2)/3)

Answer (score 0):

Your date format `yyyyMMdd` can be efficiently converted to Hive format `yyyy-MM-dd` using `regexp_replace` function instead of `unix_timestamp`+`from_unixtime` functions which are using SimpleDateFormat. Bug in your query is wrong format template, it should be 'yyyyMMdd', see [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for reference. But regexp_replace is much simpler, use `unix_timestamp`+`from_unixtime` only if not possible to do the same using regexp_replace.

Do not need to cast it to Date, string works fine.

For Hive < `1.3.0` extract month and use `ceil(month/3.0)`:

```
select ceil(month(regexp_replace('20210415','(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})','$1-$2-$3'))/3.0) -- returns 2
```

Even simpler method:

```
select ceil(regexp_extract('20210415','^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})',2)/3) --returns 2
```

And since Hive 1.3.0 there is `quarter(date/timestamp/string)` function.

Demo:

```
quarter(regexp_replace('20210415','(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})','$1-$2-$3')); --Returns 2
```